# MVVM DataService and persisting data across ViewModels

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light and I have ended up storing some data in the DataService.  This has happened because I need a place that shares some data (a list of objects) across ViewModels (I don't want the next ViewModel to go get the data from a web service again).

Am I breaking a pattern here?  It feels like I shouldn't be keeping data in the DataService and that it should only deal with the access of data and returning it to the ViewModel.  But I am finding the fact that the DataService gets inserted in to each ViewModel very useful for sharing data between them.

how else could this be done?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

If the data is in a local db on the phone, your best bet is to pass an Id from `ViewModelA` to `ViewModelB`.  In that case I believe it's ok to read the `DataService` again.

If the data is a rest service, `ViewModelA` could call `GetData(1, true);`, where the method signature in the `DataService` is `GetData(int id, refresh=false)`.  Then `ViewModelA` can pass the `Id` to `ViewModelB`.  When `ViewModelB` makes the call `GetData(1)`, you can return the cached values from the data service.  If for some reason the cached value is null, fetch it again.

I tend to follow that pattern now, I use to inject an `SharedData` singleton into any view model that needed to share data but it felt smelly.  Like a global variable.  That's probably ok for some application state things but for sharing parts of the model, it didn't feel right.  `ViewModelB` depended on `SharedData` and if that didn't get set, then what.

I'd be curious to hear how others do this.